# Passing parameter

Tags: java, queue

How to pass a parameter from the user in java lang.

for example:

I'm calling the method `enQueue(Object o)`

I want the user to enter a value for `o`

I tried
in the test class

```java
Object o = read.nextLine();
q.enQueue(o);
```

it only call the method without passing any parameter

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because `read.nextLine()` is returning nothing (`null`) or an empty string `""`.

Make sure of what's the return value by using the debugger or printing it:

```
Object o = read.nextLine();
System.out.println("I got: " + o);
```

Also, if you are only using instances of `java.lang.String` on your queue, I would recommend you using generics:

```
Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
String s = read.nextLine();
q.enQueue(s);
```